# How to determine which assertion failed in a loop?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test that loops through an array of invalid values, and asserts that each one is correctly rejected by the function.

For instance, `validateInput` should return true only if the input is a string, else return false.

```
public function testValidateInput()
{
  $obj = new MyClass();
  $data = [
    null,
    42,
    21.21,
    -24,
    -12.12,
    false,
    array('key' => 'value'),
    (object) 'value'
  ];

  foreach ($data as $item){
    $this->assertSame(false, $obj->validateInput($item));
  }
}
```

When the test fails an assertion, I only get the line number - which is the same for all the values because it's in a loop.

> ```
> 1) MyClassTest::testValidateInput
> Failed asserting that true is identical to false.
>
> /home/jeff/MyClass/tests/MyClassTest.php:24
> ```

How can I determine which value failed the assertion?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's possible to pass a last parameter as a custom message, correct? Then you can `$this->assertSame(false, $obj->validateInput($item), 'Failed to test ' . $item);` so you receive on-screen the value that failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [data provider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers). PHPUnit will then tell you what index of the provider failed.

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getInputData
 */
public function testValidateInput($value)
{
  $obj = new MyClass();

  $this->assertSame(false, $obj->validateInput($value));
}

public function getInputData()
{
    return [
      [null],
      [42],
      [21.21],
      [-24],
      [-12.12],
      [true],
      [false],
      [array('key' => 'value')],
      [(object) 'value'],
  ];
}
```

---

```
1) Test::testValidateInput with data set #3 (21.21)
Failed asserting that true matches expected false.
```

Also a hint: when asserting for boolean, use `assertFalse` method

Comment: Fabulous, thank you! Do you know why when I run the test, instead of `21.21`, it adds the smallest amount possible? `...with data set #3 (21.210000000000001)`

Comment: See the warning box at the [PHP manual on float type](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and also the linked page [Why don’t my numbers add up](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Basically, in binary representation it is impossible to represent float exactly.

Comment: Nice, good stuff. So, your posted answer here, did you manually edit it to only say `(21.21)`, or does it actually appear that way on your machine when run?

Comment: No, I have written the code and error message off the top of my head just as an example, I didn't really run any code.

Answer (score 4):

PHPUnit's assertion methods all have an additional parameter at the end that you can use for a description. Simply include the loop iteration value in the description string, and you will know exactly which one has failed.

Answer (score 1):

`assertSame` has an overload that accepts a message; you could pass along the index and the value in the message:

```
foreach ($data as $index => $item) {
    $this->assertSame(false, $obj->validateInput($item), (string)$item); // include $index too 
}
```